# Wordpress logout stuck on confirmation page

Tags: wordpress, logout, confirmation

In order to log out user from my wordpress site,I am currently using wp_logout_url(home_url()); However when I try to logout it takes me to a confirmation page (Are you sure you want to logout? page). And even if I confirm to log out, it stays on the confirmation page only. How many ever times I click on the Logout link in confirmation it stays on the same page. I notice the hyperlink generated to logout in the confirmation page is same as the confirmation page itself. Can someone tell if they faced same situation and how to resolve it ?

Thank you.

Comment: what if you try to pass no parameters to the wp_logout_url() function?

Comment: Exactly same result. If I use wp_logout_url(home_url()) it goes to http://127.0.0.1:8080/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=logout&login_videos=9999 which is the confirmation page. And the hyperlink on the confirmation page also is the same.